# What is the upsampling technique used in yolov3 upsampling layers? No resources on the internet and the original paper did not describe it well

Tags: deep-learning

There are different upsampling techniques used in different object detection algorithms but I want to 
   understand how the YOLO architecture works and in order to visualize the output of each layer and I 
   have got into trouble when I get at the upsampling layer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best thing is to look at the exact code used.

https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/blob/f6d861736038da22c9eb0739dca84003c5a5e275/src/blas.c#L334

```c
void upsample_cpu(float *in, int w, int h, int c, int batch, int stride, int forward, float scale, float *out)
{
    int i, j, k, b;
    for(b = 0; b < batch; ++b){
        for(k = 0; k < c; ++k){
            for(j = 0; j < h*stride; ++j){
                for(i = 0; i < w*stride; ++i){
                    int in_index = b*w*h*c + k*w*h + (j/stride)*w + i/stride;
                    int out_index = b*w*h*c*stride*stride + k*w*h*stride*stride + j*w*stride + i;
                    if(forward) out[out_index] = scale*in[in_index];
                    else in[in_index] += scale*out[out_index];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `float*` are the input and output images. `stride` controls how much to upsample, for a value of 2 how it is used in the [config](https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/blob/master/cfg/yolov3.cfg#L629) it doubles the width and height. `scale` is 1 it is the default parameter if no value is provided in the config ([for reference](https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/blob/b13f67bfdd87434e141af532cdb5dc1b8369aa3b/src/parser.c#L597)). All other parameters should be clear.

From what I understand it just takes one pixel in the input and for `stride = 2` writes it to 4 pixels in the output (judging from the `j/stride` and `i/stride`). So one pixel is transformed into a 4 pixels in a 2x2 area. This is probably the most naive variant of an upsampling one can implement, without any extra logic like interpolation.